# Problem in autocapitalization of text

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I had problem in auto capitalization.
I want to enter a product name which contains only a-z and 0-9. So I had taken nameField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad. I want first letter to be capital letter so I had taken nameField.autocapitalization = YES. when I entered product name for first it is taking capital letter which is working fine.
 But the problem is occurred: when I entered product name and I had poped to another view controller with out saving product name. next time if I want to enter product name it is not taking capital letter.

Please help me

Thank You
Praveena Nalajala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In :

```
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Test if you enter first letter and if YES do an `[string capitalizedString]`

Comment: Hi This is working when I entered text more than one character and it is not working when I entered only single character  for the Product name. for ex: if I had given product name as camera it is converting as Camera . But when I had entered only 'a' as product name it is not converting in to 'A'.